# in cublasSgemm(), does the transpose option really create a temp copy of a transposed A?

Tags: gpu, blas, cublas

in the gemm() function http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm 
 you can specify CUBLAS_OP_T

what happens under the hood ? does CUBLAS silently create a copy of the transposed input, inside device space, or does it simply operate on the original, simply changing the order indices are used? (for example A[i * n +j] ===> A[j * m + i])

if it's actually creating a copy, I should avoid it, due to the extra cost in time and space, because my input matrices are huge

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is no physical transpose done (memory doesn't change). But memory is 1D, so the difference between an NxM and a transposed MxN matrix is just a matter of interpreation. Deep down, it's indeed a matter of swapping which index is considered "major". Since BLAS originates in FORTRAN, the "N" is column-major and "T" is row-major.